# How to get character pressed on virtual keyboard using jkeyboard plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

[I am using a library from git for a virtual keyboard](https://github.com/javidan/jkeyboard) . The library has a file called jkeyboard.js that contains (in part) the code below:

```
  type: function (key) {
        var input = this.settings.input,
            val = input.val(),
            input_node = input.get(0),
            start = input_node.selectionStart,
            end = input_node.selectionEnd;

        var max_length = $(input).attr("maxlength");
        if (start == end && end == val.length) {
            if (!max_length || val.length < max_length) {
                input.val(val + key);
            }
        } else {
            var new_string = this.insertToString(start, end, val, key);
            input.val(new_string);
            start++;
            end = start;
            input_node.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        }

        input.trigger('focus');

        if (shift && !capslock) {
            this.toggleShiftOff();
        }

      return key; // added myself
    },
```

Full code for jkeyboard.js can be found [here](https://github.com/javidan/jkeyboard/blob/master/lib/js/jkeyboard.js)

I also have my own file my_file.js with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     
     $('#keyboard').jkeyboard({ // basic setup from docs
        input: $('#search_field')
    });
    
});
```

How do I call the code in jkeyboard from my file and get the character that was pressed on the virtual keyboard? The docs are pretty bare and I was unable to find anything online. I am not the greatest at JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: just edit the plugin code and put  your function call in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do u mean by calling code in jkeyboard?
if the code already in function you just can call in your js file using it's function name. or you can modify the code, make it inside function and call it

```
function_name(response){
  ... // do with response
 }
```

and make sure your jkeyboard script above your js script

```
<script src="jkeyboard.js"></script>
<script src="your_js.js"></script>
```

or the simplest way just try to get value from the input element.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Keyboard Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/css/jkeyboard.css">
    <style>
        body{
            background: #144766
        }
        .hidden-keyboard{
            visibility: hidden;
        }
            
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <input type="text" class="hidden-keyboard" id="input-field">
    <div id="keyboard"></div>
    

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/js/jkeyboard.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#keyboard').jkeyboard({
            layout: "english_capital",
            input: $('#input-field'),
            customLayouts: {
                selectable: ["english_capital"],
                english_capital: [
                    ['Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P',],
                    ['A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L',],
                    ['Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M', '\'', '.'],
                    ['space', '-', 'backspace']
                    ],
            }
        });

        $(document).on("click", "#keyboard", function(){
            var value_input = $("#input-field").val()
            console.log(value_input)
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but the function doesn't have a name. I want to get the key pressed from that function in my code but I am unable to call it. It just says type: function(key) ... I have tried several things but unable to access it.

Comment: I know it's a dirty way, but you can get character from input element. If you don't want to show the input, use  `visibility: hidden` on input element, and then use  `val()`

Comment: Yea, that's what I was thinking too. Can you please update your answer to show me how to do that? You can add it to your existing answer.

Comment: I edited my answer, and already test it. and it worked.

Comment: @krystallix doesn't work in snippet

Comment: @krystallix This works for me - thanks so much!

Comment: @FlashThunder ofc it won't work in snippet.  because **link to jkeyboard library** is in local directory, so we must download the library and include it manually to local directory

Comment: @krystallix you could give a link from the repository

Comment: @FlashThunder yes I would if there is a link to css or js from repository. but there is no link I can use from there. need to upload it manually to cloud platform. I was browsing the library cdn on google but still got nothing. so yeah, I included it manually.